# unable to rotate a div in javascript

Tags: javascript

i cant rotate a div in js with an eventlistener and dont know how to fix it. however i do know the problem (i think, im probably incorrect): its NaN. when the parseFloat() checks the rotate, it cant find the number because it thinks its a string, so it returns NaN.

theres also another problem. when the div is going in a direction, the border is vanishing away. dont know how to fix it either.

EDIT: I want the div to move but also rotate at the same time, forgot to add that.

https://jsfiddle.net/CarelessInternet/4cxgnerv/

(basically showing the problem below a bit, just check the jsfiddle please, thanks)

```
var transformLeft = false,
transformRight = false,

var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("square")),
transformLeft = parseFloat(computedStyle.transform),
transformRight = parseFloat(computedStyle.transform);

if (transformLeft == true) {
    transformLeft = transformLeft + 5;
    square.style.transform = 'rotate(' + transformLeft + 'deg)';
} else if (transformRight == true) {
    transformRight = transformRight + 5;
    square.style.transform = 'rotate(' + transformRight + 'deg)';
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve regarding the rotation? To make the square always point in the movement direction?

Comment: PS... don't use `left, top`, use `translate`  to move your character. Will run smoothlier.

Comment: So: you declare variables `transformLeft` and `transformRight`, initialize their values to false, but immediately redeclare them, assign both of them the same value `parseFloat(computedStyle.transform)` - what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Totally forgot, I wanted it to move but also rotate at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your code:

1. `getComputedStyle` returns a CSSStyleDeclaration Object. That means that it consists of all the compute css values of an element. So when you access `computedStyle.transform` you get a string with the transformation matrix of the element as a result and *not* a integer or decimal value.
2. Your usage of `transformLeft` and `transformRight` is at least confusing if not wrong. You use them as booleans containing true or false and then at other times integers.

Comment: 2. Oh yeah, I didn't notice that when I was making it. I was in a bit of a rush when I was making the code. I didn't really check through the code that much when I was rechecking.